# Listing all the services I use on AWS via JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I'm playing with `NodeJS` and learning `AWS` along the way, so I would like to get all the services I'm running on my `AWS` account. Then I would like to group them logically (ie `compute`, `database` etc) and visualize them with some JS library.

Is there a way to retrieve all this data from my AWS environment via the `JavaScript AWS SDK`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no API that will give you a list of services that you use, at least not in the format you're requesting, what you can do is use the cost and usage API to return services which you are utilising some cost for:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cost-explorer/

You can filter based on multiple criteria and with a few simple enums you should be able to achieve what you need.